# disable safari error alerts

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, web

I used following code to disable javascript alerts

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

it disables all other alerts except safari browser error alerts while running on Iphone, like invalid address alert.
how can i disable these error alerts on safari?

Answer (score -2):

May be, the better way is to avoid calling alert function from your code?